# React nested component touch event stop propagation is not working / event bubbling

Tags: reactjs, mobile, event-handling, touch, event-bubbling

I have a parent component which has sections switching based on swipe up and down. There is a child container which needs to have content scrolling if the content is overflown. Mouse wheel events will trigger for both parent and child, if child component is in view it will only do scrolling the content and event will not be propagated to parent to switch between section. But the same is not working for touch devices.

The below image is the page containing one parent(which is one section) where different sections will be loaded on swipe up or down.

[image]

The below image is child component, which is toggled when any of the above list item is clicked. Here the scrolling works absolutely fine for desktop mouse wheen and laptop touch pad. But when we use mobile device the scrolling is switching the parent sections but not scrolling the content. 
[image]

I have tried the event stop propagation on the child component scroll container for touch events.

We can see code as below in child component render method:

```
<BodyContent onWheel={this.stopPropagation}
                            onTouchEnd={this.stopPropagation}
                            onTouchMove={this.stopPropagation}
                            onTouchStart={this.stopPropagation}>
                            <BodyHeader>
                                {content.title}
                            </BodyHeader>
                            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: 
                                  content.mainText }} />
                        </BodyContent>
```

The below code is function in the child component class.

```
stopPropagation(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
}
```

Sorry I cannot copy all the code as per the guidelines. 
Any quick help is appreciated and Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about putting "pointer-events: none" on the parent container when the child is visible?

Comment: I will try that now

Comment: any luck with the above approach?

Comment: @IshmeetSingh Hey thanks, Actually for parent sections I am using it like fullpage section scrolling which has swipe events. The library I am using is this one https://github.com/subtirelumihail/react-fullpage . Basically there is an option in this library called scrollBar true/false which disables the swipe events for mobile. I was trying to toggle this flag when child container is in view but I am getting react errors such as setState is not possible on unmounted component. What you suggested is good approach but how to apply on this library exposed component (parent - section container).

Comment: I want to help you but with so little information I cannot. You can check out the list of issues in that library's GitHub page.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am using styled components, I probably try the above css bit by passing props to by extending that library component.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. I have solved in different way to not get into the trap of child and parent both have swipe events. So I have moved the child component as a sibling component to parent component. It just worked independently.